# how to normalize a column in hive?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, normalize

I'm trying to normalize a column in hive, which means I have to make each value in the column divide max value in that column. For example: I have a table X:

```
A   B   C   D
1  0.1  3  0.2
2  0.2  4  0.5
3  0.3  5  0.2
```

I want to normalize column C, the requested table Y is:

```
A   B    C    D
1  0.1  0.6  0.2
2  0.2  0.8  0.5
3  0.3   1   0.2
```

I do not know how to write SQL to express the max value of the whole column.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`max` window function

```
select a
      ,b
      ,c / max(c) over () as c
      ,d

from x
```

---

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+
| a |  b  |  c  |  d  |
+---+-----+-----+-----+
| 1 | 0.1 | 0.6 | 0.2 |
| 2 | 0.2 | 0.8 | 0.5 |
| 3 | 0.3 | 1   | 0.2 |
+---+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

select a,b, c/(Select MXA(C) from X),d From X

Comment: Have you seen the Hive tag?